# How do I change the timeout constraint when calling a WebService from a Silverlight 4.0 app?

Tags: c#, silverlight, web-services, silverlight-4.0

How do I change the timeout constraint when calling a WebService from a Silverlight 4.0 app? It doesn't have a Timeout property attached to it like it seems to have had before.

Edit: Anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the ServiceReferences.ClientConfig file:

```
<binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
                     maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
                     sendTimeout="00:02:00"
                     openTimeout="00:02:00"
                     receiveTimeout="00:02:00"
                     closeTimeout="00:02:00"/>
```